# mysql configuration on 2 core 2.90GZ, 26GB of Memory windows DB server

Tags: mysql, database, configuration

I am very relatively new on handling db server and all my life I am have manage a database good for development, now it is my first time handling an enterprise level database with 0 knowledge on configuration.

On Postgresql there are tools online that could assist me but on mysql I cannot find a tool that will help me distinguish a good configuration on our DB server.

Here are the specs:
OS: Windows server 2012 (64 bit)
Ram: 24 GB
Processor: 2 core 2.90GHZ

this server will be used primarily for a ticketing system that generates at least > 1000 issue tickets per day, add to that it will query to retrieve info and also 2000 users will be using it assuming  1000 user will be active on a day shift, 1000 user will be active on the night shift.

Many thanks guys.

Comment: You already asked this same question on dba.stackexchange.com, which is a more appropriate place to ask it. StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: the link to question on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211830/i-got-a-2-core-mysql-server-with-20-gb-of-ram-1-tb-of-hard-drive-running-on-win)